# Concrete examples of statements not provable in PRA + $\epsilon_0$-induction that are provable in PA?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, peano-arithmetic

It is well-known that $\mathbf{PRA}$ plus $\epsilon_0$-induction on bounded formulas cannot prove all $\mathbf{PA}$ theorems ([essentially because $I\Sigma_1$ plus $\epsilon_0$-induction on bounded formulas is finitely axiomatizable while the latter isn't](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130538/how-do-we-know-pa-is-incomparable-with-pra-epsilon-0)). Are there any concrete examples known (preferable "natural")?

(This is an exact copy of [my question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769889/concrete-examples-of-statements-not-provable-in-pra-epsilon-0-induction-tha), but I expect I won't get any answer there, so I hope I'm allowed to cross-post it here)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “$\epsilon_0$-induction”? The schema of $\epsilon_0$-induction for all formulas most definitely proves the schema of $\omega$-induction for all formulas, i.e., PA. The schema is not finitely axiomatizable unless it is restricted to formulas of complexity $\Sigma_n$, or something. (PRA is *also* not finitely axiomatizable, by the way.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Oh, yes, sorry: on bounded formulas. And yes, thanks for pointing that out, I meant: essentially because $I\Sigma_1$ is finitely axiomatizable. I hope it is good now :)

Comment: Ok. (The single axiom equivalent to) $I\Sigma_2$ is not provable in $I\Sigma_1+{}$ bounded $\epsilon_0$-induction (as the latter is a consistent $\Pi_3$ theory, while the former implies the uniform $\Sigma_3$-reflection principle). Is that concrete enough?

Comment: @Emil That sounds pretty concrete, although I cannot really follow the argument (I'm just starting out in proof theory). I've only come across reflection in the case of Con(PA) is equivalent to $\Pi_1$ reflection.

Comment: Another point: it leaves open the question of a "natural" example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One example is $I\Sigma_2$ (or rather, the conjunction of its finite axiomatization).

Notice that the theory $I\Sigma_1+\epsilon_0$-*induction for bounded formulas* is axiomatized by $\Pi_3$ sentences: in particular, the $\epsilon_0$-induction schema can be written in prenex form as
$$\forall u\,\forall x\,\exists y\,\forall z\,\bigl[\bigl(\neg\theta(u,y)\land(z\prec y\to\theta(u,z))\bigr)\lor\theta(u,x)\bigr],$$
where $\theta\in\Delta_0$ and $\prec$ is the order representing $\epsilon_0$. By a theorem of Leivant [1], $I\Sigma_2$ is not provable from any set of $\Pi_3$ (or even $\Sigma_4$) sentences consistent with $Q$. More generally, for $n\ge1$, $I\Sigma_n$ is not provable from any set of $\Sigma_{n+2}$ sentences consistent with $Q$.

The reason is that $I\Sigma_n$ proves the uniform $\Sigma_{n+1}$-reflection schema for $Q$:
$$\mathrm\forall x\,\bigl(\mathrm{Pr}_Q(\ulcorner\phi(\dot x)\urcorner)\to\phi(x)\bigr),\qquad\phi\in\Sigma_{n+1},$$
where $\mathrm{Pr}_Q$ denotes the formalized provability predicate for $Q$. This schema is equivalent to the single sentence
$$\def\rfn{\mathrm{RFN}}\rfn_Q(\Sigma_{n+1})=\forall x\,\bigl(\mathrm{Pr}_Q(x)\to\mathrm{Tr}_{n+1}(x)\bigr),$$
where $\mathrm{Tr}_{n+1}$ is the truth definition for $\Sigma_{n+1}$-formulas (defined so that it is vacuously true for non-$\Sigma_{n+1}$-formulas). Moreover, it is easy to see that
$$\rfn_Q(\Sigma_{n+1})\equiv\rfn_Q(\Pi_{n+2}).$$
Now, if we assume for contradiction that $\rfn_Q(\Pi_{n+2})$ is provable from a consistent extension of $Q$ by $\Sigma_{n+2}$ sentences, there is a single $\Sigma_{n+2}$ sentence $\phi$ consistent with $Q$ such that
$$Q+\phi\vdash\rfn_Q(\Pi_{n+2})\vdash\mathrm{Pr}_Q(\ulcorner\neg\phi\urcorner)\to\neg\phi,$$
that is,
$$Q+\phi\vdash\mathrm{Con}_{Q+\phi},$$
contradicting the second incompleteness theorem.

**Reference:**

[1] Daniel Leivant: *The optimality of induction as an axiomatization of arithmetic*, Journal of Symbolic Logic 48 (1983), no. 1, pp. 182–184, doi: [10.2307/2273332](https://doi.org/10.2307/2273332).

Comment: Yes! Thanks! And this only uses the consistency of PRA + $\epsilon_0$-induction, but you need that anyway, otherwise the result is of course false. A few short questions: 1) what do you mean with "uniform"? 2) is it hard to show that $I\Sigma_n$ proves the uniform $I\Sigma_{n+1}$-reflection schema for $Q$? 3) What is the complexity of the truth predicate of up to $n$ quantifiers ($\text{Tr}_n$); I think $\Delta_n$?

Comment: I've accepted your answer; but I remind that the question of a natural example is still open. Or are there such that imply $I\Sigma_2$ easily?

Comment: (1) What I presented above are called *uniform* (or *global*) *reflection principles*, as opposed to *local reflection principles*, which are the schemata $\mathrm{Pr}_Q(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)\to\phi$ for sentences $\phi$. (2) It’s not that easy, as it relies on cut elimination. But basically, you convert a proof of a $\Sigma_{n+1}$ sentence into a cut-free sequent refutation of its negation $\psi$, which is $\Pi_{n+1}$; assuming for contradiction that $\psi$ is true, you prove by induction that all the sequents in the proof with $\psi$ removed are true. This is $\Pi_n$-induction, ...

Comment: ... as apart from $\psi$, all the sequents have $\Sigma_n$ antecedents and $\Pi_n$ succedents. (3) The truth definition for $\Sigma_n$ formulas is $\Sigma_n$.

Comment: I know about cut elimination, but I don't understand what you mean by "a cut-free sequent refutation of its negation $\psi$".

Comment: We are proving inside $I\Sigma_n$ that if a sentence $\phi\in\Sigma_{n+1}$ is provable in $Q$, then $\phi$ is true. $\psi$ is $\neg\phi$, written in a prenex normal form so that $\psi\in\Pi_{n+1}$. A refutation of $\psi$ is a proof of the sequent $\psi\Longrightarrow{}$. Though now that I think about it, it’s not necessary to make the proof into a refutation. We can just take directly a cut-free proof of $\Longrightarrow\phi$, and assuming $\phi$ is false, show by induction that all sequents in the proof with $\phi$ deleted are true.

Comment: First, a truth definition for $\Sigma_n$ formulas is $\Sigma_n$, and a truth definition for $\Pi_n$ formulas is $\Pi_n$. You can’t mix the two. Cut-free sequent calculus has the subformula property, respecting the polarity of subformulas, hence in a proof of a $\Sigma_{n+1}$  sentence $\phi$ (with a single leading $\exists$ quantifier), every sequent in the proof has $\phi$ and $\Pi_n$ formulas in the succedent, and $\Sigma_n$ (really, $\Pi_{n-1}$) formulas in the antecedent. A truth definition for such sequents can be written as $\Pi_n$ as the semantics of sequents effectively negates ...

Comment: ... formulas in the antecedent, except that you can only apply the truth definition to the part of the sequent without $\phi$, as $\phi$ itself has too large complexity. This is the reason why you have to check the truth of $\phi$ before the inductive argument. If it’s true, we are done as that’s what we want to prove, and if it’s false, we have to obtain a contradiction. So, assume it is false, and consider a $\Pi_n$ truth definition for sequents in the proof that fixes the value of $\phi$ as false, and evaluates other formulas in the normal way. Then, using $\Pi_n$ induction (which is ...

Comment: ... equivalent to $I\Sigma_n$, see e.g. Hájek&Pudlák), prove that all sequents in the proof are valid under this truth definition. In the end, you obtain that the empty sequent (that is, $\Longrightarrow\phi$ with $\phi$ discarded as false) is valid, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I think I must be confusing some of your terminology: OK, we have a cut free proof of $\implies \phi$, and we can prove (using our $\Pi_n$ truth definition) that all sequent above this are true (what do you mean by valid?), and we have $\neg\phi$ (for contradiction). How does that lead to a prove of the empty sequent?

Comment: Valid just means true under all assignments. The last sequent of the proof is $\Longrightarrow\phi$. Under the truth definitoin that fixes $\phi$ as false, or equivalently, that removes it from the succedent of any sequent before checking its truth, this is the same as the empty sequent $\Longrightarrow$.

Comment: By the way, I really really appreciate all your help and comment. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see. That clarifies it. It's not about obtaining a proof of the empty sequent, rather on the assumption of $\neg\phi$, you obtain that the empty sequent is true, which by definition of the (adjusted) truth predicate is impossible. Right? I'm trying to think why we need $\neg\phi$ to change the truth definition. It seems we can just "hard code" the falsehood of $\phi$ in it no matter what.

Comment: If you hardcode $\phi$ as false, you need $\phi$ to be actually false in order to prove soundness of the inference rules for the induction step. In particular, write $\phi=\exists x\,\psi(x)$, and consider an $\exists$-right inference from $\Gamma\Longrightarrow\Delta,\psi(t)$ to $\Gamma\Longrightarrow\Delta,\phi$.

Comment: Yes, I see. If we know $\phi$ to be false then so must $\psi(t)$, and hence if $\Gamma \implies \Delta, \psi(t)$ is true, one of $\Delta$ must be true, or one of $\Gamma$ be false, but under these conditions $\Gamma \implies \Delta,\phi$ is true, so we remain in good shape.

Comment: The final thing I don't understand is why your $\Sigma_{n+1}$ reflection scheme proves $\text{RFN}(\Sigma_{n+1})$ over $I\Sigma_n$? What is the complexity by the way of $I\Sigma_n$? as a single sentence? $\Pi_{n+3}$?

Comment: $I\Sigma_n$ is $\Pi_{n+2}$, just count the quantifiers. You would know this if you looked at the Leivant paper in the first place. Concerning the **FINAL THING**, let $\psi$ be a conjunction of axioms of $I\Delta_0+\mathrm{EXP}$ (which is $\Pi_2$, and enough to verify the properties of $\mathrm{Tr}_n$), and given a $Q$-proof of a $\Sigma_{n+1}$ sentence $\sigma$ (the “$x$”), construct a proof of $\psi\to\mathrm{Tr}_{n+1}(\ulcorner\sigma\urcorner)$, and apply the reflection principle.

Comment: That's okay. Thank-you for all the help. There is no supervisor and MSE usually doesn't answer in this area. I will definitely look at the paper, I think with a bit of patience I should have the level to process it. I'm not a PhD student btw. Again, thanks for your help. I'm sorry to have bothered you so often.

Comment: That was a typo, by the way, I meant $I\Sigma_{n+1}$.